# Using an NLP vectorized output for subsequent model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I use SpaCy to output a vectorized array of my text field. I'm having issues plugging this output into my random forest and could use some guidance. I label encoded other fields so my pandas dataframe looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

d = {'le1': [0,1,2,1], 'le2': [3,0,2,1], 'spacy_output':[[0.12,0.14,3.5],[1.21,0.84,1.92],[0.34,0.85,2.43],[0.09,0.18,2.21]], 'response':[0,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then I try to plug this into my model:

```
X = np.array(df.drop('response', axis=1))
y = df['response'].values.ravel()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 23)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=100, criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Confused on how to pass this dataframe to my model. I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spacy_output column in your DataFrame is a list of lists, so when you convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array using np.array, you end up with a 2D array where each element is a list. This causes problems when you try to pass this array to the RandomForestClassifier because the classifier expects a 2D array of numerical values.

```
d = {'le1': [0,1,2,1], 'le2': [3,0,2,1], 'spacy_output':[[0.12,0.14,3.5],[1.21,0.84,1.92],[0.34,0.85,2.43],[0.09,0.18,2.21]], 'response':[0,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

X = np.concatenate([np.array(df[['le1', 'le2']]), np.array(df['spacy_output'].tolist())], axis=1)
y = df['response'].values.ravel()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't sure if this approach would result in any loss of information for the classifier